# VLookUp ComboBox input to update TextBox values

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, vlookup, userform

My issue is once choosing a country from a drop-down list(ComboBox) within my UserForm, my textboxes are not showing any output. Nothing happens. The text boxes are supposed to perform a VLookUp on whatever value is selected in the ComboBox. The ComboBox (Name) is "Country".

Code for one of the TextBoxes:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Worksheets("All Countries Validation").Range("A:R")
TextBox2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Country.Value, myRange, 2, False)
```

Comment: Probably need to do some debugging, like what is the value of Country? Try Debug.Print(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Country.Value, myRange, 2, False)). Also why define a range of A:R when you only want column 2? Finally, try Application.Vlookup without the .WorksheetFunction, it yields a different class of error messages that might help.

Comment: So I tried doing the debug and nothing happened. I also created a button to display a message box of "Country.value" yet nothing happened when I clicked it. If I choose a country and hit the Enter key on my keyboard while within the ComboBox I get an Automation Error, The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Comment: Idk if it makes a difference, but this is taking place within a UserForm with tabs. This is the second tab within the UserForm

Comment: Do you have the immediate window open so you can see the results of Debug.Print? (View > Immediate Window on the menu bar). It would be best to put the debug line on the line before TextBox2.Value = etc. When you're testing, is there actually data for the country in question - do you expect to find anything? Is there more than one row pertaining to a country e.g. same country on multiple rows?

Comment: Ignore that, see user3598756's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use `Country_Change()` event handler instead of `TextBox2_Change()` one

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Country_Change()
    Dim myRange As Range, f As Range

    Set myRange = Worksheets("All Countries Validation").Range("A:A")

    Set f = myRange.Find(What:=Country.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<--| try and find combobox selected value
    If f Is Nothing Then '<--| if not found ...
        TextBox2.Value = "" '<--| ... then clear textbox
    Else'<--| ... otherwise...
        TextBox2.Value = f.Offset(, 1) '<--| ... fill it with proper value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Doh, bit obvious >.< +1 for this

Comment: This worked perfectly! I just saw many places online do it the method that I tried, but this was much more efficient and it actually worked ha